# What are these symbols in 'bytes' type?

Tags: python, binary, byte

So, I have a single byte in bytes format looking something like that:

```
b'\xFF'
```

It is quite easy to understand that a single byte is the two symbols(0-F) after '\x'

But sometimes the pattern doesn't match, containing more than two symbols after '\x'.

So, for example, if I use **secrets.token_bytes()** I can get something like that:

```
>>> import secrets
>>> secrets.token_bytes(32)
b't\xbcJ\xf0'
```

Or, using **hashlib** module:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha256('abc'.encode()).digest()
b'\xbax\x16\xbf\x8f\x01\xcf\xeaAA@\xde]\xae"#\xb0\x03a\xa3\x96\x17z\x9c\xb4\x10\xffa\xf2\x00\x15\xad'
```

So, can someone, please, explain what are those additional symbols purpose and how are they generated?
Thanks!

Comment: This is just python's way of representing 'unprintable' characters in a string with binary content. All the `\xhh` characters are a hex representation. All the others are literal ascii characters. It is easy to spot the occasional hex character amongst lots of ascii, but more difficult the other way round as you demonstrated in the `hashlib digest`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a quirk of the way Python prints byte strings.  If the byte value is one of the printable ASCII characters it will print that character; otherwise it prints the hex escape.

Show `bytes(range(0x100))` to see it visually.

To get a string that consistently uses hex escapes, you need to build it yourself.

```
print(''.join(f'\\x{i:02x}' for i in bytes(range(0x100))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So, they are actually 'stored' as a pattern '\xNN' where N is 0-f, but if you try to print them out, python will replace some bytes that match particular ASCII symbol with that symbol, right?
Also is there a way to represent 'bytes' object without this replacement?

Comment: There's also the `hex()` function of a python bytes object, which prints the hex values (without the '\x' though). I.e.: `bytes(range(0x100)).hex()`.